# operating system memory allocation

Tags: operating-system

I understand each process is given a block of memory,which contains code segment,data segment ,heap and stack.And also that the code segment is read only.But when a process starts running,where is this read only memory allocated and how does the OS distinguish the read only 
part of memory for each process?

Comment: It's in RAM (or virtual memory), and it's distinguished by having a "read-only" attribute set in the page table.

Answer (score 0):

Each process has what's called a page table which maps actual physical RAM to the virtual memory space of the process. This table assigns attributes to each 'page' of memory, typically 4kb. Some of these attributes include setting the page as read-only, as not executable, as having privileged code, etc. The operating system basically tells the hardware what the attributes are so that it does not have to micromanage every memory access, as this would be very inefficient.

For low-level details consult [this osdev wikipage](http://wiki.osdev.org/Paging)  for explanations and examples in typical x86 machines.